# Hibernate Configuration on JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, jboss

I have a problem with Hibernate configuration on my JBoss server. I paste hibernate.cfg.xml with two configuration, old that works, and new that dosen't work. Everything seems to be ok, but I'm still getting errors that log shows.

```
Hibernate.cfg.xml:
```

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <!-- New but not working configuration -->
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:/App/TimerDS</property>

    <!-- Old configuration -->
    <!-- property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property -->

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <!--property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property-->

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- validate / create / update / create-drop -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <mapping resource="com/icarer/timer/model/models.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

```
Log
14:36:01,559 ERROR [com.icarer.timer.messaging.eventstore.EventStoreChangesHandlerImpl] (EJB default - 2) Error while executing getChanges() from EventHandler : org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
at com.icarer.timer.messaging.eventstore.EventStoreChangesHandlerImpl.getChanges(EventStoreChangesHandlerImpl.java:96) [classes:]
at com.icarer.timer.concrete.ListenerServiceImpl.listen(ListenerServiceImpl.java:46) [classes:]
at com.icarer.timer.Timer.doWorkListener(Timer.java:36) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:280) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:61) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:159) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:1068)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:758)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
... 52 more
```

Comment: Read the message: "You cannot commit during a managed transaction!". The app server starts, commits and rollbacks transactions for you. That's the main advantage of using EJBs. But you're trying to commit explicitely. The problem is not the config. The problem is your code.